# Running-order of nested function-calls delayed/altered due to URLloader in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

First of all: English is not my first language. ;-)

I am compiling the following code:

```
var sqldata:String;
function sql(saveorload,sqlstring) {
    var sqlloader = new URLLoader();
    var sqlrequest = new URLRequest("http://***/sql.php");
    sqlrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sqlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sqldonetrace);

    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.sqlm = saveorload;
    variables.sqlq = sqlstring;
    sqlrequest.data = variables;

    sqlloader.load(sqlrequest);
}
function sqldonetrace(e:Event) {
    sqldata = e.target.data;
}
sql("1","SELECT * FROM songs WHERE `flag2` LIKE '0'");
trace (sqldata);
```

So, here comes the problem:
"sqldata" is traced as "null". AS3 seems to run "sql", then "trace" and then "sqldone", but i would need sql -> sqldone -> trace...
I can't put the trace-command in the sqldone-function because it is stored as *.as and loaded at different points in my .swf and not always followed by only a trace-command.

Any Ideas/hints/flaws in script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actionscript is, by design, an event driven language. It also guarantees that the code executes in a single thread i.e. if a function call starts, no other(new call) actionscript code would execute until the first call finishes.

That being said, what you should have is to pass a complete handler to sql(...).

```
function sql(saveorload:String, sqlstring:String, completeHandler:Function):void
{
    var sqlloader = new URLLoader();
    var sqlrequest = new URLRequest("http://***/sql.php");
    sqlrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sqlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);//tell urlloader to use the complete handler passed in parameters    
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.sqlm = saveorload;
    variables.sqlq = sqlstring;
    sqlrequest.data = variables;

    sqlloader.load(sqlrequest);
}
```

And then use it from some other place like:

```
sql("1","SELECT * FROM songs WHERE `flag2` LIKE '0'", sqldonetrace);
function sqldonetrace(e:Event)
{
    var sqldata:String = e.target.data;
    trace (sqldata);
}
```

Also, I think you should check for error events from urlloader. Pass another parameter to sql as errorHandler

Comment: ...actually so simple... thank you very much. I do have eventlisteners for errors, but wanted to keep it as simple as possible here.